# Matlab cvx: Difference of convex function programming error

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, cvx

I am trying to do a difference of convex function (DC) programming problem in CVX for a polynomial. The objective function is convex and there is a non-convex polynomial inequality. It is known that for any polynomial $f(x)$, a suitable convex decomposition of the function which is twice differentiable defined in a compact convex set $\Omega$ is

\begin{align}
f(x) = (f(x)+\eta\frac{\lvert|x\rvert|^2}{2})-(\eta\frac{\lvert|x\rvert|^2}{2})
\end{align} 
where $\eta$ is greater than the spectral value of the Hessian of the polynomial $f(x)$ [Tuy, Convex Analysis and Global Optimization, pp-113]. 
For a non-convex polynomial inequality:
\begin{align}
f(x)\leq 0
\end{align}
A suitable convex relaxation of the inequality is given by linearizing the negative quadratic part in the above equation about the point $y$ 
\begin{align}
f(x)+\eta\frac{\lvert|x\rvert|^2}{2}-(\eta\frac{\lvert|y\rvert|^2}{2}+\eta y^{T}(x-y))\leq 0
\end{align}
The optimization with the relaxed convex inequality is carried out sequentially by updating $y$ until convergence is met.

In my case, the polynomial is cubic and when I implement this on CVX, I get a disciplined convex programming error.
 Illegal operation: {convex} - {convex}
while defining the cubic polynomial.

Is there a flaw in my logic?

Comment: I have edited the question for additional clarity. Its not a typo since I am trying to represent the non-convex polynomial as difference of two convex polynomials.

Comment: If $f(x)$ is a cubic polynomial, what's $\eta$?  The cubic term will dominate the quadratic term.

Comment: Show your CVX code if you want help diagnosing the problem.  Or post at http://ask.cvxr.com/ .  If you declared y as a CVX variable, which it should not be, then you will get a CVX error.

Comment: Also f(x) still needs to comply with CVX's DCP rules. The fact that $f(x) + \eta \|X\|^2/2$ is convex, doesn't mean you can enter it in violation of CVX's rules.